# get data using hive from data generated using a map reduce program in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am beginner to hadoop . I have successfully installed hadoop by following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10 and followed example for map reduce program on word count provided at http://www.evanconkle.com/2012/02/writing-hadoop-mapreduce-program-php/ .
and all the steps are scussfully completed and i can see the results .

Now I want to use some kind sql operation on the data generated by the mapreduce program like getting all the words which are counting more than 25.

How can i proceed on this .I need some guidance

Answer (score 0):

For sql in Hadoop you have to use Hive. So firstly you have to install it on Hadoop. After that, you can run some query in the HQL wich is very similar to SQL. Refer here : https://hive.apache.org/

Comment: For HIVE we need the data in ORC file . how we can save result of mapreduce job into ORC file .

Comment: You can write in a file with "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY ...". You can find the documentation here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries